# Is there a way to document a legacy APEX application

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have inherited a legacy-build Oracle Application Express (APEX) app.
Before I make changes to update functionality, I want to document the application.

Right now, I'm trying to document by visiting each page and writing down the title, objects, buttons, noting links to other pages, etc.

Is there an easier way?  Are there any built-ins or plug-ins that would make that easier?

The original was in pre-4.2.1, the current APEX is 5.1.1

Comment: This is a very open question, I think you'll find the answer is subjective. Ultimately, you can always take a copy of the application, and never modify the copy.

Comment: @Scott, Thank you for replying.  I have made a copy.  I don't know a good way to ensure that I understand a legacy application.  In my mind, that would be outlining the page structures, noting the objects on page, tracing the operations workflow, etc.  I'm trying to do that manually, but that's open to my carelessness.  
I was hoping that there would be:
 a built-in capability that I am just not familiar with; some best practice that I'm not aware of; some easier way than visiting every page and drilling in to every objects; etc.  
If not, then I'm stuck and will continue manually.

Answer (score 1):

There are no plug-ins or built-in tools available that would help achieve this. However, since you are looking for best practices, instead of looking at the application from the page flows, first look at preparing the ERD.

The design process for database-driven applications, like the ones built in Oracle APEX, begin with a database modeling exercise, which involves mapping real-life entities into relational tables and defining the properties and relationships between these entities or tables.

Once that is in place, then you would start designing the page flows and build the client side logic. Following, the same approach while trying to deconstruct database driven applications is a commonly followed best practice approach.